# Why does the volume not decrease when I move away from the AudioSource?

Tags: unity, audio

I created a simple scene with an audio source and a player that can move. The main camera is a child object of the player. I set the audio source volume rolloff to "logarithmic rolloff". As far as I understand, this means that the sound should become weak very fast when the main camera moves away from the audio source. But this does not happen: as I move the player (with the camera) away from the audio source, the volume remains the same. I see, in the rolloff graph of the audio source, a line denoted by "Listener", which moves to the right as the camera moves away from the source. But still, the volume remains the same. Why?

Comment: Have you tried moving the player absurdly far from the audio source, to ensure that the effect is not simply scaled incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that you have set ***Spatial Blend*** **to "3D"**. The slider is two entries above the 3D Sound Settings collapsible section (in my version of Unity). You can also enter a value from 0 to 1, with 1 for full 3D. The slider position defaults to 0 for 2D, which will override any 3D settings you configure in the lower section.